# Python - Can't go through "Open URL: xxx Always open this type of links in the associated application"

Tags: python, web-scraping, chromium

This is my first topic and question. I'm trying to write a script in Python(Pycharm) which help me log on to SAP via Citrix from the browser level. My problem is that I can't go through the window that pops out:

Open URL: xxx Always open this type of links in the associated application.

My script:

```
*imports that I need*
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\User\Chromium\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://XYZ.dk')

Detect_Reciver = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="protocolhandler-welcome"]/div/div/div/div/a')
if Detect_Reciver == Detect_Reciver:
Detect_Reciver.click()
time.sleep(2)
```

The problem appears here, after loading on a new page, the "Open URL: xxx Always open this type of links in the associated application." pops out, and I want to Press Enter or Escape by Python. Send_keys(keys.ENTER/ESCAPE) doesn't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8TT3.png)
Can you help me out :)?